# Calculating area weighted average in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, area, india, weighted-overlay

I want to calculate area weighted average of districts of India.

I have Particulate matter 2.5(PM2.5) data for Districts of India, and now I want to find area weighted average of PM2.5 for each of these districts.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the approach of creating [spatial weight index](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-statistics-toolbox/generate-spatial-weights-matrix.htm) it is defined as:

> A spatial weights matrix is a representation of the spatial structure of your data. It is a quantification of the spatial relationships that exist among the features in your dataset (or, at least, a quantification of the way you conceptualize those relationships). Because the spatial weights matrix imposes a structure on your data, you should select a conceptualization that best reflects how features actually interact with each other (giving thought, of course, to what it is you are trying to measure). If you are measuring clustering of a particular species of seed-propagating tree in a forest, for example, some form of inverse distance is probably most appropriate. However, if you are assessing the geographic distribution of a region's commuters, travel time or travel cost might be a better choice.

[image]

*Spatial relationships based on polygon contiguity, Queen's case: shared edges or nodes*

I also came across another approach from a different thread posted, [Calculating area weighted average of attribute in one layer by shape in another using ArcGIS for Desktop?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/136809/calculating-area-weighted-average-of-attribute-in-one-layer-by-shape-in-another)

That might also shed some light on an approach to help you.